# SOAP requestRecipientToken - any recent API changes?

Tags: docusignapi

I am getting "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope" error for new envelopeID: f3a10b34-8f37-41fd-9338-e3a48b30acec
Whereas, I receive embedded link response for previous envelopes with envelopeID: 531e6028-b246-4227-ae45-1c5ad61f89ed.

Am I doing anything wrong or this is a new issue?Can you please look into this?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, this is tested using our demo account..

Answer (score 0):

Never mind,  my mistake. I missed to set RecipientCaptiveInfo info for an envelope.